# Typescript in react: Array of objects that contains an array of a string and sometimes an JSX element

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am building a table framework with a filter function. Each row contains every column and the column content is an array of strings, and in some cases (when I need format it even html as a JSX element. I need the strings for sorting, filtering and the JSX for display. Maybe I am totally wrong, but It worked very well until it doesn't. Due to the error message in the editor it seems to be typescript that doesn't like strings and JSX element if not there from the beginning. I have no Typescript definition of the array itself. The "expanded" column is holding information that can be edited based on filtering result like:

```
Default:
myCols = [{col1: ["Row 1, Col 1",<span className="alert">Row 1, Col 1<span>], col2: ["Row 1, Col 2"], expanded: ["Expandable content of Row 1"]}]

After filtering:
[{col1: ["Row 1, Col 1",<span className="alert">Row 1, Col 1<span>], col2: ["Row 1, Col 2"], expanded: ["Expandable content of Row 1", <>Expandable <mark>content</mark> of Row 1</>]}]
```

Maybe I am all wrong, If so, how should I handle the data and the visible data in my table component? Any ideas?

Comment: First, what is "the error message in the editor"? It's hard to tell what you are asking. Are you asking how to type an array that contains `string`s and JSX? Because that's easy `const array: (string | JSX.Element)[] = []` See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCtCAOwGd4UooAuOACgamBoHM4APnABSAZQAaAOgCiAGyQgkNGAEoA2gF04AXjhr8KOgBN8GikyiSwAVzoALdgB46YFDQB8AMQgRHAehc3dxUgA). But you also seem to be asking if this is a good approach, and it's hard to answer that from your question. Can you describe your goal in more detail here?

Comment: Yeah you are right, sorry about such a bad question. The problem was to type the array containing string and JSX and it were here the editor returned an error message. Thanks for your help!

Next time I will write my question(s) in a less desperate state, for a more proper way ;)